# How to implement an AST given a grammar with JJTree

Tags: grammar, javacc

I'm trying to implement a parser from LaTeX to HTML, to complete my exercise I need to write a JavaCC grammar, generate the Abstract syntax tree and implement a visitor to parse the code.

I've written my .jj grammar file, now I'm confused about how to use jjtree to generate the AST based on grammar file. Anyone can help me?
Here you are my grammar file, if it can help.

```
ArrayList<LaTeXObject> LaTeX() :
{
    ArrayList<LaTeXObject> objects;
}
{
    objects = ObjectList() <EOF>

    {
        return objects;
    }
}

ArrayList<LaTeXObject> ObjectList() :
{
    ArrayList<LaTeXObject> objects = new ArrayList<LaTeXObject>();

    LaTeXObject object;
}
{
    ( object = Object() { objects.add(object); } )*

    {
        return objects;
    }
}

LaTeXObject Object() :
{
    LaTeXObject object;
}
{
    (
        object = Command()
        |
        object = Group()
        |
        object = String()
    )

    {
        return object;
    }
}

LaTeXCommand Command() :
{
    String name;
}
{
    <BACKSLASH>
    (
        name = Name() Whitespace()
        |
        name = SpecialCharacter()
        |
        name = NonSpecialCharacter()
    )

    {
        return new LaTeXCommand(name);
    }
}

String Name() :
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    Token token;
}
{
    token = <ASCII_LETTER> { sb.append(token.image); } ( LOOKAHEAD( <ASCII_LETTER> ) token = <ASCII_LETTER> { sb.append(token.image); } )*

    {
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

void Whitespace() :
{}
{
    ( LOOKAHEAD( WhitespaceCharacter() ) WhitespaceCharacter() )*
}

String WhitespaceCharacter() :
{
    Token token;
}
{
    token = <WHITESPACE>

    {
        return token.image;
    }
}

String SpecialCharacter() :
{
    Token token;
}
{
    (
        token = <BACKSLASH>
        |
        token = <LBRACE>
        |
        token = <RBRACE>
        |
        token = <SPECIAL>
    )

    {
        return token.image;
    }
}

String NonSpecialCharacter() :
{
    Token token;
}
{
    token = <NON_SPECIAL>

    {
        return token.image;
    }
}

LaTeXGroup Group() :
{
    ArrayList<LaTeXObject> objects;
}
{
    <LBRACE> objects = ObjectList() <RBRACE>

    {
        return new LaTeXGroup(objects);
    }
}

LaTeXString String() :
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String string;
}
{
    string = TextCharacter() { sb.append(string); } ( LOOKAHEAD( TextCharacter() ) string = TextCharacter() { sb.append(string); } )*

    {
        return new LaTeXString(sb.toString());
    }
}

String TextCharacter() :
{
    Token token;
}
{
    (
        token = <WHITESPACE>
        |
        token = <NON_SPECIAL>
        |
        token = <SPECIAL> 
        |
        token = <ASCII_LETTER>
        |
        token = <ASCII_DIGIT>
        |
        token = <LATIN_SUPPLEMENT>
        |
        token = <UNICODE_LETTER>
    )

    {
        return token.image;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you have now does build an abstract syntax tree.  If you are happy with that, you don't need JJTree at all.

If you really want to use JJTree, you should strip out all the code that makes `LatexObject`objects.  Just make all your nonterminal productions return `void`. Also rename the file from `.jj` to `.jjt`.  Now run JJTree with your `.jjt` files as input.  Low and behold you'll have a new `.jj` file that builds an abstract syntax tree.  Now fiddle with the `.jjt` file until the abstract syntax tree it produces is one you are happy with.